# No output for dereference operator and endl

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to get my head around pointers and cant understand why using the dereference operator to print a value works fine when `"\n";` is added to the line, but for some reason I dont get any output when I use `endl;`. The terminal shows no output with `endl;`. Is this something to do with [output buffer flushing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arrayA[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int * ptr_P;

    ptr_P = arrayA;
    for (int i; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cout << *ptr_P << "\n"; // Works fine, but endl; does not
        ptr_P++;
    }
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: It works for me with endl... there is no reason it wouldn't. Are you sure you rebuilt the program properly?

Comment: Can't believe it. The only scenario where endl is not working is when endl is redefined to something else. So please try to not use `using namespace std` and replace `endl` with `std::endl`

Comment: Just replacing "\n" with endl. I am using Netbeans 8. That is my whole program above. std::endl didnt fix the issue. So confused

Comment: Often you don't really need `std::endl`, just writing `'\n'` for the end-of-line, and flush only when really needed. And remember that output streams are flushed when the stream is closed, which happens when the program exits.

Comment: If I type make testprogam in a terminal and then ./testprogram I still get nothing..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not initialising `i`:

```
for (int i; i < 6; i++)
```

This should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
```

otherwise you have undefined behaviour and your loop may not execute at all.

---

Note that any good compiler with suitable warnings enabled would have pointed out this mistake to you and saved you some time and effort:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:10:14: warning: 'i' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     for (int i; i < 6; i++)
              ^
```